# Tune slow grouping functions Invantive SQL

Tags: postgresql, performance, invantive-sql

I have a database on PostgreSQL with some very large tables (with events and event measurements). For a date range on the measurement and one event type I want to compute the average duration with Invantive SQL.

events (simplified, approximately 5 GB):

- id
- type_code

event_measurements, approximately 50 GB:

- event_id
- started
- ended

When I run a query like

```
select avg(ended - started) 
from events 
   join event_measurements on events.id = event_measurements.event_id 
where events.type_code = '...'
```

it runs for hours consuming GBs of internal memory.

Necessary indexes are all in place, including foreign key indexes.

From the session I/Os, I've seen that Invantive SQL first downloads the details and performs the grouping on the client. That is fine with small volumes, but in this case I would like to have more native performance like 5 minutes for such a query.

The surrounding queries require Invantive SQL, so "force native SQL" switch on the database is not an option.

How I can improve the performance of this query, without switching to "force native SQL"?

Comment: http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/SlowQueryQuestions

Comment: Create a view in Postgres and access the results through the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to creating a view as suggested by @GordonLinoff, you can also use:

- `local log on` to switch connection between individual statements, and
- `insert into nativeplatformrequests(payload_text) values ( 'select avg...')` to bypass Invantive SQL. It is like `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` on Oracle.